# Multipe client to one server, Java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I create a simple game with high scores..I have a simple txt file of all the scores.

Now I need that this file will be shared on the server side, if I understand it well.

I found this solution [Multipe client to one server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131377/socket-programming-multiple-client-to-one-server) but cant realy understand what I need to do.

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you explain it more thoroughly? What are you trying to do, what have you tried to do, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [socket programming multiple client to one server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10131377/socket-programming-multiple-client-to-one-server)

Comment: The question that you link to has an answer that can be adapted to your purpose.

Comment: I have a simple txt file of high scores.. I need that the cilents will see this file and they will can to write into it and read from it..So any client will know which place he is on the game.. How I can do that? to share the file on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to build some API/Web Service for this, using Sockets or with REST. Then clients will send request for resource and get response with scores.